# GUI of Java Project is empty and white

Tags: java, window

On my current project everything worked when I used my project as an applet, but after I changed to a frame project and implemented all required parameters, the outgoing window is just white. I don't get any error when compiling the code, but as I said I cant start it :( Would be very good if somebody can look the whole code up and explain why the window is white, I would also send some Bitcoin like some dollars to thank you :)

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Gui extends Frame
{ 

 public static void main (String[] args) {

    }     

 BorderLayout b1 = new BorderLayout();  

 int anzahl;
 int ascii;
 int e;

 TextField name = new TextField(8);
 Button confirm2 = new Button("Einfügen");
 TextField name2 = new TextField(5);
 Button confirm3 = new Button("Suchen");
 Choice HashMethod = new Choice();

 Panel b = new Panel();
 Panel c = new Panel();
 Panel a = new Panel();
 Label[] lab = new Label[10];


    public Gui() { 

    super();
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) { dispose(); }
    });
    int frameWidth = 300; 
    int frameHeight = 300;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setTitle("Gui");
    setResizable(false);
    Panel cp = new Panel(null);
    add(cp);
    setVisible(true);


    b.add(name); 
    b.add(confirm2);
    b.add(HashMethod);
    c.add(name2);
    c.add(confirm3);
    this.add(b,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(a,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(c,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 


 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     lab[i]=new Label("leer");
    }



  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
     a.add(lab[i]);
    }

 } 

}
```

Comment: `setVisible(true);` should be invoked after everything is prepared. Move it at the end of Gui constructor. Also avoid using `null` as layout manager like in `new Panel(null);`. Oh and consider moving to Swing instead of AWT so start using `JFrame` instead of `Frame`, `JButton` instead of `Button` and so on.

Comment: What should I use Instead of "new Panel(null);"

Comment: Instead of `Panel` use `JPanel`. And don't provide *any* argument. Try with `new JPanel()` (you may need to change also variable type).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Frame and then add your BorderPane to it to make it visible.

EDIT:
I made some changes to your code and I have gotten it to work. I simply changed this.add(a,BorderLayout.CENTER); to this.add(a,BorderLayout.WEST);

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;




public class Gui extends Frame
{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Gui frame = new Gui();

}

BorderLayout b1 = new BorderLayout();

int anzahl;
int ascii;
int e;

TextField name = new TextField(8);
Button confirm2 = new Button("Einfügen");
TextField name2 = new TextField(5);
Button confirm3 = new Button("Suchen");
Choice HashMethod = new Choice();

Panel b = new Panel();
Panel c = new Panel();
Panel a = new Panel();
Label[] lab = new Label[10];


public Gui() {

    super();

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) { dispose(); }
    });
    int frameWidth = 300;
    int frameHeight = 300;
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setTitle("Gui");
    setResizable(false);
    Panel cp = new Panel(b1);
    b1.setHgap(0);
    add(cp);
    setVisible(true);


    b.add(name);
    b.add(confirm2);
    b.add(HashMethod);
    c.add(name2);
    c.add(confirm3);

    this.add(b,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(a,BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(c,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        lab[i]=new Label("leer");
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        a.add(lab[i]);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry I really dont know how to do this exactly ;(